# convert array value to string value with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array

```
let arr = [12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67]
```

i want the result back as string

```
let strArr = "12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67"
```

Please some one suggest me any solution

Comment: just make `arr + ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toString()` method:

```js
let arr = [12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67];
arr = arr.toString();
console.log(arr);
console.log(typeof arr);
```

You can read more about this **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)**.

Comment: Felicitari for this nice solution. +1

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, multumesc :). Same goes for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `join` method.

> The join() method joins the elements of an array into a string, and
>   returns the string.

```js
let arr = [12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67]
let strArr = arr.join();
console.log(strArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**.

The join() method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string.

```js
var a = [12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67];
a.join(); // '12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this would be to use [join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```
let arr = [12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67]
let strArr = arr.join();
```

Second you be to use [toString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp)

```
 let arr = [12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67]
 let strArr = arr.toString();
```

Because you want to join by a comma, they are basically identical, but join allow you to chose a value separator.

Answer (score 1):

JS type coercion is sometimes useful.

```
var arr = [12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67],
strArr  = arr + ""; // <- "12,12,43,53,56,7,854,3,64,35,24,67"
```